# How would I sort a 2D array of strings to display the top 5 most occurring Names?

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array

My goal with my program is to take a 2D array that is storing names and sort them from the most occurring to least occurring. In this array there are multiple occurrences of the same name.
The desired output should look like this:

```
TOP 5 PLAYERS
1. GEORGE - WINS: X
2. HENRY - WINS: X
3. JOHN - WINS: X
4. MARRY - WINS: X
5. JULIA - WINS: X
```

Where X represents the amount of times their name occurs in the 2D array.

Unfortunately due to my professors rules, we aren't allowed to use anything from the <string.h> library. We are only permitted functions from the <stdio.h> library.

Here's what my function looks like at the moment. I'm pulling the names from a file named scores.txt and saving them to the array and displaying them. I just don't have a way to order them.

```
void leaderboard(FILE *scores) {
    
    int totalNames = 4;
    int row;
    char tempName[MAX_USERNAME_CHARS-1];
    char namesArray[500][MAX_USERNAME_CHARS-1];
    
    scores = fopen("scores.txt","r");
    
        while (fscanf(scores,"%s",tempName) == 1) {
            int strlength;
            for (strlength = 0; tempName[strlength] != '\0';strlength++);
            
            for (int i=0; i <= strlength; i++) {
                namesArray[row][i] = tempName[i];
            }
            row++;
        }
    
    //Insert Sorting Code Here
    
    printf("\nTOP 5 PLAYERS\n");
    for (int i=0;i<=totalNames;i++) {
        printf("%d. ",i+1);
        for (int j=0;j<=MAX_USERNAME_CHARS-2;j++) {
            printf("%c",namesArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" - WINS: X\n");
    }
}
```

This function currently only prints out the first 5 names it grabs from the file.

Comment: There are a few problems, other than that you do not actually count or sort anything. 'row' is not initialised. You cannot assume an uninitialised variable is zero. When you print the names, you assume that all names are MAX_USERNAME_CHARS-2 long, rather than stopping at a '\0'. And your version of strlen() and strcpy() only work by accident I think, because of the <= in the copy.

Comment: I'd advise putting things into functions. If you're not allowed to use string.h, implement your own versions of functions that you'd like to use from there. Make your own explicit my_strlen() and my_strcpy() functions, and get them working first. (And you probably don't need a strlen() if you make a functional strcpy()). And if your namesArray[] contains zero terminated strings, you can just printf("%s", ...) them. No need for a loop.

Comment: You are being asked to generate a _**histogram**_. Once you have that, you can sort the histogram based on the frequency/count, then print. You do not need to store an array of unsorted-with-duplicates names: Each time you read a name, add it to the histogram.